# How to destroy servlet before creation?

Tags: java, servlets

I had been asked a question in interview, how will you stop a Servlet from instantiating a servlet object? 
I said the container decides to destroy servlet object.

He said again that the container will first create the servlet object and then destroy it. My question is servlet object hasn't been created yet, so there is no point in destroying it. How will you code a servlet class when it is trying to instantiate itself trap in severe problem and our code(or any other way) should stop it from instantiating?

Comment: Put code into the init() method to prevent creation would be my guess.  Is this common?  I've never done it.  Why ask such a thing in an interview?  The question tells as much about them as your answer does about you.  I'd run from a company that cared about such silly puzzles and gotchas.

Comment: throw an exception in the constructor I guess

Comment: Throwing exception in init() seems a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the container from creating an instance of the Servlet in three ways:

1. Remove the reference to the Servlet in web.xml. If your container is processing annotations, then the `@WebServlet` annotation also need to be removed.
2. In the constructor, throw an exception.
3. In the init() method, throw an exception.

Comment: invoking init() gives servletness to the created object. So if we invoke init() which throws exception doesn' create servletness but still object is there in the heap with non-servlet features. We can invoke init method because object is created already. I found your second option is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess he is expecting you to throw `javax.servlet.UnavailableException` from `init()`

> public class UnavailableException
>   extends ServletException
>   This exception indicates that a servlet is unavailable. Servlets may report this exception at any time, and the network service running the servlet should behave appropriately. There are two types of unavailability, and sophisticated services will to deal with these differently:
>
> Permanent unavailability. The servlet will not be able to handle client requests until some administrative action is taken to correct a servlet problem. For example, the servlet might be misconfigured, or the state of the servlet may be corrupted. Well written servlets will log both the error and the corrective action which an administrator must perform to let the servlet become available.
>
> Temporary unavailability. The servlet can not handle requests at this moment due to a system-wide problem. For example, a third tier server might not be accessible, or there may be insufficient memory or disk storage to handle requests. The problem may be self correcting, such as those due to excessive load, or corrective action may need to be taken by an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, container is responsible on servlet creation and life cycle. It first creates instance of servlet using default public constructor, then calls its `init()` method. When container wants to destroy the servlet it calls its `destroy()` method that is typically (IMHO) empty.

Container can first destroy and then create new servlet during hot re-deployment when it deploys probably new version of your application. Probably this is what your interviewer wanted to hear from you.